# Using user input and IndexOf to print

Tags: java

I need to check user input for abbreviations.
The user enters a specific line at the beginning of the program and the `indexOf` should not be used to recognize the abbreviations.
Any other input, the abbreviations should be recognized.
I've tried many, many variations and can't list them all, but here are two of my latest code efforts.

**Scenario 1**
The `userInput1` is `static`.
The `userInput` should print out what the user inputs (system generated) and then put the abbreviations on different lines.
I'm not sure if I even need two variables, but that is the only way I can think of to separate the `indexOf` statements from the `userInput1` variable.

When this code runs, the `userInput1` prints as output on every line.
Also, when the output prints what is inputted, only the first word is listed of the sentence.
I am very confused and would appreciate any help.
I've tried else if with errors.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TextMsgDecoder {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter text: ");
        String userInput = ""; 
        String userInput1 = "";

        userInput1 = scnr.next();
        userInput = scnr.next( );

        if (userInput1.equals("IDK if I'll go. It's my BFF's birthday."));{
            System.out.println("IDK if I'll go. It's my BFF's birthday.");
        }

        if (userInput.equals("")); {
            System.out.println("You entered: " + userInput);
        }
        if (userInput.indexOf("BFF")== -1) {
            System.out.println("BFF: best friend forever");
        }
        if (userInput.indexOf("IDK")== -1) {
            System.out.println("IDK: I don't know");
        }
        if (userInput.indexOf("JK")== -1) {
            System.out.println("JK: just kidding");
        }  
        if (userInput.indexOf("TMI")== -1) {
            System.out.println("TMI: too much information");
        }
        if (userInput.indexOf("TTYL")== -1) {
            System.out.println("TTYL: talk to you later");
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

Here is the expected and actual output.

1. Compare output

Input

```
IDK if I'll go. It's my BFF's birthday.
```

Your output starts with

```
Enter text: 
IDK if I'll go. It's my BFF's birthday.
You entered: if
BFF: best f
```

Expected output starts with

```
Enter text: 
You entered: IDK if I'll go. It's my BFF's birthday.
```

2. Compare output

Input

```
Nice pic, TMI haha JK. TTYL
```

Your output starts with

```
Enter text: 
IDK if I'll go. It's my BFF's birthday.
You entered: pic,
BFF: best friend forever
```

Expected output starts with

```
Enter text: 
You entered: Nice pic, TMI haha JK. TTYL
```

3. Compare output

Input

```
IDK if I'll go. It's my BFF's birthday.
```

Your output

```
Enter text: 
IDK if I'll go. It's my BFF's birthday.
You entered: if
BFF: best friend forever
IDK: I don't know
JK: just kidding
TMI: too much information
TTYL: talk to you later
```

Expected output

```
Enter text: 
You entered: IDK if I'll go. It's my BFF's birthday.
BFF: best friend forever
IDK: I don't know
```

4. Compare output

0/1

Input

```
Nice pic, TMI haha JK. TTYL
```

Your output

```
Enter text: 
IDK if I'll go. It's my BFF's birthday.
You entered: pic,
BFF: best friend forever
IDK: I don't know
JK: just kidding
TMI: too much information
TTYL: talk to you later
```

Expected output

```
Enter text: 
You entered: Nice pic, TMI haha JK. TTYL
JK: just kidding
TMI: too much information
TTYL: talk to you later
```

---

Here is my 2nd try without the 2 variables.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TextMsgDecoder {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
          Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter text: ");
 String userInput = ""; 


userInput = scnr.next( );

 if (userInput.equals("")); {
         System.out.println("You entered: " + userInput);
}
     if (userInput.indexOf("BFF")!= -1) {
         System.out.println("BFF: best friend forever");
      }
     if (userInput.indexOf("IDK")!= -1) {
         System.out.println("IDK: I don't know");
      }
     if (userInput.indexOf("JK")!= -1) {
         System.out.println("JK: just kidding");
      }  
     if (userInput.indexOf("TMI")!= -1) {
         System.out.println("TMI: too much information");
      }
     if (userInput.indexOf("TTYL")!= -1) {
         System.out.println("TTYL: talk to you later");
      }

      return;
   }
}
```

1. Compare output

Input

```
IDK if I'll go. It's my BFF's birthday.
```

Your output starts with

```
Enter text: 
You entered: IDK
IDK: I don't know
```

Expected output starts with

```
Enter text: 
You entered: IDK if I'll go. It's my BFF's birthday.
```

2. Compare output

Input

```
Nice pic, TMI haha JK. TTYL
```

Your output starts with

```
Enter text: 
You entered: Nice
```

Expected output starts with

```
Enter text: 
You entered: Nice pic, TMI haha JK. TTYL
```

3. Compare output

Input

```
IDK if I'll go. It's my BFF's birthday.
```

Your output

```
Enter text: 
You entered: IDK
IDK: I don't know
```

Expected output

```
Enter text: 
You entered: IDK if I'll go. It's my BFF's birthday.
BFF: best friend forever
IDK: I don't know
```

4. Compare output

Input

```
Nice pic, TMI haha JK. TTYL
```

Your output

```
Enter text: 
You entered: Nice
```

Expected output

```
Enter text: 
You entered: Nice pic, TMI haha JK. TTYL
JK: just kidding
TMI: too much information
TTYL: talk to you later
```

Comment: toooo long question, can you make it short please ? 

Comment: take the semicolons off the end of your if statements. Any semicolon at the end of any if will ignore it and continues on to the next line no matter the condition of the if. For instance you'll always hit this line System.out.println("IDK if I'll go. It's my BFF's birthday.");

Comment: I tried my best to format the question, but please [edit] yourself with a [mcve]. Only show **one or two** "inputs and outputs". I think we get the idea that you are wanting to "expand" the "texting code", so no need to dump the entire test-cases into your question.

Comment: "I need to check user input for abbreviations. The user enters a specific line at the beginning of the program **and the indexOf should not be used** to recognize the abbreviations. Any other input, the abbreviations should be recognized."       This problem description makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Some problems worth pointing out:

1. You want to check `indexOf() != -1` to see if the string **does contain** the abbreviation. Therefore, the second code is closer.
2. You need to use `scnr.nextLine()` to read entire **lines**, not words.
3. Unclear why you care about empty strings... `userInput.equals("")`. You should print nothing in that case. Maybe you want `if (!userInput.isEmpty())`, and then print `"You entered: " + userInput`?
4. Test your code in smaller portions. One abbreviation at a time.

---

Here is a small example of the proper code

```
    System.out.println("Enter text: ");
    String userInput = scnr.nextLine();  // IDK if I'll go. It's my BFF's birthday.

    if (!userInput.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("You entered: " + userInput);
    }

    if (userInput.indexOf("BFF") != -1) {
        System.out.println("BFF: best friend forever");
    }
    if (userInput.indexOf("IDK") != -1) {
        System.out.println("IDK: I don't know");
    }
```

Output

```
Enter text: 
You entered: IDK if I'll go. It's my BFF's birthday.
BFF: best friend forever
IDK: I don't know
```

---

**Suggestion** HashMaps work better (spoilers)

> ```
> Map abbrevs = new LinkedHashMap() {{
>    put("BFF", "best friend forever");
>    put("IDK", "I don't know");
>  }};
>
>  System.out.println("Enter text: ");
>  String userInput = scnr.nextLine();  // IDK if I'll go. It's my BFF's birthday.
>
>
>  if (!userInput.isEmpty()) {
>      System.out.println("You entered: " + userInput);
>  }
>
>
>  for (String key : abbrevs.keySet()) {
>      if (userInput.indexOf(key) != -1) {
>          System.out.printf("%s: %s\n", key, abbrevs.get(key));
>      }
>  }
> ```